# Extract <b> text from a table

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hi my python code to extract the Best Seller Rank of a book on Amazon is:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
from time import sleep

def parse(url):
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
for i in range(20):
    sleep(3)
    try:
        doc = html.fromstring(page.content)
        XPATH_BSR = '//li[@id="SalesRank"]//text()'
```

Take this book for example: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/0965437221](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0965437221)

I only want the best seller number of 590345 but instead my output is a mess:

Thanks.

{'BSR': 'Amazon Best Sellers Rank: \n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '#590,345 in Books (See Top 100 in Books)\n'
         ' \n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '.zg_hrsr { margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style-type: none; }\n'
         '.zg_hrsr_item { margin: 0 0 0 10px; }\n'
         '.zg_hrsr_rank { display: inline-block; width: 80px; text-align: '
         'right; }\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '\n'
         '    \n'
         '    #4774\n'
         '    in\xa0Books > Health, Fitness & Dieting > Mental Health > '
         'Happiness\n'
         '    \n'
         '    \n'
         '    #55298\n'
         '    in\xa0Books > Self-Help',

Comment: What are you using to execute the XPath?

Comment: Can you please include the section of your script where you use this `//li[@...` code

Comment: More complete script included, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't know which library are you using or anything. I'll leave you with this solution which uses requests-html library.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
session = HTMLSession()
page = session.get('https://www.amazon.com/dp/0965437221')
rank = page.html.find("#SalesRank").text.split('#')[1].split()[0]
print(rank)
```

Other way, assuming your output above is string would be to extract rank directly, like this:

```
rank = your_output.split('#')[1].split()[0]
print(rank)
```